# Freebsd's Xorg on zenbook

Tags: xorg

Is there any specific video drivers for current zenbook laptops that would support xorg? Current layout throwing the machine into the reboot as soon as x is touching monitor config. Model `ux461`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turned out UHD 620 chip in this zenbook is not supported and I need to install `drm-devel-kmod`.